# Overloading methods for parametrized struct

Tags: struct, julia, overloading

## Short Version

I have a struct like

```
@kwdef mutable struct Params{B, C}
    a::Float64 = 42
end
```

where `B` and `C` are symbols that will determine which function to use out of many functions that are overloaded for different combinations of symbols. The valid symbols would be for example `:constant` and `:exponential`. I want to write a function that will be invoked if one of the symbols matches the corresponding symbol in the parametrized struct, and it should also be invoked *regardless* of the other symbol. So as an example,

```
p = Params{:constant, :gaussian}()
foo(p::Params{:constant, <:Symbol}) = 42
foo(p) # should return 42, but throws an error
```

How can I do this?

## Context

I am implementing a dynamic rule (to be used with DynamicalSystems.jl) for which one term of the rule is computed using the PDF of the gaussian distribution, a reciprocal function,
or is constant (see supplementary information as well as figure 3 of ["Quantitative modeling of the terminal differentiation of B cells and mechanisms of lymphomagenesis"](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1113019109)). Using a simplified model, see the below code as an example of what I want to do:

```
using UnPack
using DynamicalSystems
using Distributions

@kwdef mutable struct Params{B, C}
    mu_p    = 10e-6
    sigma_p = 9
    mu_b    = 2
    sigma_b = 100
    mu_r    = 0.1
    sigma_r = 2.6
    
    bcr_0   = 0.05
    cd_0    = 0.025
end

function germinal_center_regulation_rule(u, params, t)
    @unpack mu_p, sigma_p, mu_b, sigma_b, mu_r, sigma_r, 
    @unpack bcr0, cd0 = params
    p, b, r = u
    #######IMPORTANT PART############
    bcr = compute_bcr(;u, params, t)
    cd40 = compute_cd40(;u, params, t)
    #################################
    pdot = mu_p + sigma_p/b
    bdot = mu_p + sigma_p/b - bcr*b
    rdot = mu_r * sigma_r/r
    return SVector(pdot, bdot, rdot)
    
# Different methods for different parameterized struct
compute_bcr(;u, params::Params{:constant, <:Symbol}, t) = 15
compute_bcr(;u, params::Params{:gaussian, <:Symbol}, t) = pdf(Normal(), t)
compute_cd40(;u, params::Params{<:Symbol, :reciprocal}, t) = params[:bcr0]/u[2]
compute_cd40(;u, params::Params{<:Symbol, :gaussian}, t) = pdf(Normal(), t)

# Example usage
p_constant_bcr_gaussian_cd40 = Params{:constant, :gaussian}()
u0 = [0.2, 5.0, 0.2]
mixed_ds = CoupledODEs(
  germinal_center_regulation_rule, u0, p_constant_bcr_gaussian_cd40)
total_time = 200
X, t = trajectory(ds, total_time)

p_gaussian_bcr_gaussian_cd40 = Params{:gaussian, :gaussian}()
gaussian_ds = CoupledODEs(
  germinal_center_regulation_rule, u0, p_gaussian_bcr_gaussian_cd40)
total_time = 200
X, t = trajectory(ds, total_time)
```

Comment: One thing to note aside from the question you asked: `Params` in combination with DynamicalSystems sounds like something that you might iterate over. Both value-types and mutable structs can be quite bad for performance (see e.g. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-value-type). If performance is of any concern for you, you might want to reconsider if it really needs to be mutable and if setting up proper subtypes / a type hierarchy might not be the better approach than value-types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The comment about performance and type hierarchy is addressed in one of the answers below, which I have accepted since performance is always a concern if I am simulating dynamical systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by BallpointPen in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77190173/13389627), you can make this work by not using the subtype operator `<:` for value types in the type parameters. I am not sure whether DynamicalSystems.jl mandates the use of symbols in your case, but in case it doesn't, IMO it is a better idea to just let the type system work for you.

Create a new abstract type and derive your parameter types from it.

```
abstract type AbstractParamType end

struct Constant <: AbstractParamType end
struct Exponential <: AbstractParamType end
struct Reciprocal <: AbstractParamType end
struct Gaussian <: AbstractParamType end
```

Then use this abstract type in the definition of `Params`

```
@kwdef struct Params{P1 <: AbstractParamType, P2 <: AbstractParamType}
    mu_p    = 10e-6
    sigma_p = 9
    mu_b    = 2
    sigma_b = 100
    mu_r    = 0.1
    sigma_r = 2.6
    
    bcr_0   = 0.05
    cd_0    = 0.025
end
```

so that you can define methods on the parameters this way.

```
compute_bcr(;u, params::Params{Constant, <:AbstractParamType}, t) = 15
compute_bcr(;u, params::Params{Gaussian, <:AbstractParamType}, t) = pdf(Normal(), t)
compute_cd40(;u, params::Params{<:AbstractParamType, Reciprocal}, t) = params[:bcr0]/u[2]
compute_cd40(;u, params::Params{<:AbstractParamType, Gaussian}, t) = pdf(Normal(), t)
```

This has a few advantages over using values as type parameters:

- The manual check of the type parameters in the `Params` constructor is no longer required in the constructor.
- Invalid states are not representable -- the original `Params` constructor will accept any symbols as type parameters and restricting them artificially would require another manual check. The checks are now handled entirely by the type system.
- Adding new kinds of type parameters is still as easy as before.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `T<:U` indicates that `T` is a subtype of `U`. But in your case, `:gaussian` is not a *subtype* of `Symbol`, but rather *is* a `Symbol`. You can fix this with

```
foo(p::Params{:constant, S}) where {S} = 42
```

If you must ensure that `S` is a `Symbol`, it's best to do so in `Params`’s constructor.

```
julia> @kwdef mutable struct Params{B, C}
           a::Float64 = 42
           function Params{B, C}(a) where {B, C}
               if !(B isa Symbol && C isa Symbol)
                   error("Params generics must be Symbols")
               end
               return new{B, C}(a)
           end
       end

julia> Params{:a, :b}(2)
Params{:a, :b}(2.0)

julia> Params{:a, 1}(2)
ERROR: Params generics must be Symbols
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:35
 [2] Params{:a, 1}(a::Int64)
   @ Main ./REPL[49]:5
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[51]:1
```